# code not working on machine

Tags: xcode, swift

i am having an issue with code not working on my machine, the code its self is perfectly valid and compiles and runs on my girlfriends machine, however on my machine is giving me errors

```
imageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "Shake For Shot00000"),
        UIImage(named: "Shake For Shot00001"),
        UIImage(named: "Shake For Shot00002"),
```

at the very start of that code its telling me `UIImage` does not conform to protocol any object, then after i finish this array of uiimages i have

```
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1.0
```

and that is giving me type int does not conform to protocol `FloatLiteralConvertible`.

i have run this same project folder on my girlfriends machine and it runs 100% fine, i have tried reinstalling Xcode and even reformatted my computer and a fresh install of mavericks and Xcode, nothing is working, i was hoping someone has had simmalir issues and can point me in the direction of fixing this short of buying a new machine

Answer (score 0):

```
var animationRepeatCount: Int // 0 means infinite (default is 0)
```

so change 1.0 to 1 and try again.